# Many-To-One selection

Tags: select, iteration, wildcard, abap, many-to-one

While programming at work, a friend presented me a very interesting case:
There is a table with wildcard values, such as "*test*". This register is able to find words containing `'test'` in them, as it does not matter what comes before or after the word.

There is another table which holds registers with the desired text, such as `'this is a test'` for example.

The regular access preference would be from the wildcard table to the text table, but this is not possible in my friend's scenario.

He actually came with a solution, but it doesn't feel it is as good as it could be.

His idea was to select every wildcard register and every text needed. Then, he would delete from the wild card table every register which did not have a matching target in the text table, as it is already correct and containing only pertinent values.

In ABAP this could be written as:

```
data: 
     wa_wildcard   type          string,
     t_wildcards   type table of string,
     t_texts       type table of string,
     wa_text       type          string,
     lv_index      type          sy-tabix,
     lv_found      type          c.

select * from zt_texts into table t_texts. "Retrieves desired texts.
check sy-subrc is initial.

select * from zt_wildcards into table t_wildcards. "Retrieves all widlcards.
check sy-subrc is initial.

loop at t_wildcards into wa_wildcard. "Checks every Wildcard
  move lv_index to sy-tabix. "Stores the iteration index for Wildcard table.

  loop at t_texts into wa_text. "Checks if the actual wildcard matches any text retrieved.
    if wa_text cp wa_wildcard-value. "If text contain parts of the wildcard string, it matches
      move 'X' to lv_found. "Found a match, may exit the loop!
      exit.
    endif.
  endloop.

  if lv_found ne 'X'.
    delete t_wildcards index lv_index. "removes the wildcard if no match was found.
  endif.
endloop.
```

Since this is done in ABAP, i thought there would be a select statement capable of doing this validation process directly into the database, for the wildcard table may be too big to select everything, iterate, and process.

EDIT: The general Idea is to use the text to find appropriate wildcards for it, without testing every single wildcard with every single text. I would like to know if this is possible to be implemented in any solution, be it database-oriented, i.e in a select statement or in pure code.

Comment: How big is too big? And btw, that ABAP Coding should be taken out and shot. Please do NOT take this as an example of how to write ABAP programs.

Comment: This is not a proper code, it is something I wrote just to explain how the scenario works and for people with no ABAP knowledge to understand it better. The 'big' factor is not only number of entries, but unnecessary processing. Imagine the wildcard table had 200,000 entries, the text table had 600,000  and no matches were found (hypothetical scenario).

Comment: There is no magic that will save you from checking every wildcard against every table entry. The only question is whether you want to offload that processing to your most expensive resource (the database servers) or keep it in the ABAP processing...

Comment: Exactly. However, there may be some optimizations before that. There are, of course, the check for duplicate entries, blank entries and whatnot. I was thinking about an operation that is the exact opposite of CP (contain parts) since it forces the check of the wildcard on the text, while the other way around, passing the text and returning matching wildcards, seems to have a better performance and readibility.

Comment: It might be just my understanding, but what you write does not make any sense to me. "Passing the text and returning wildcards" - how is that supposed to work at all?

Comment: I'm sorry, I know this is a strange topic and may be difficult to understand. Thing is, you know how you can search things with wild cards such as `*code*here*` and match it with `I have a code located in here`? I want to know if there is a way to do the exact thing backwards, using the text to get the wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a better method depending on how many entries you expect to select.  It requires as many database accesses for `ZTEXT` as there are entries in `ZWILDCARD`, but if that's a small number, this will reduce the load.

```
select * from zwildcard into t_wildcards.

loop at t_wildcards into  wa_wildcard.
  select * from ztext appending table t_texts
    where value LIKE wa_wildcard.
  if sy-subrc is not initial.
    delete t_wildcards index sy-index.
  endif.
endloop.
```

This is assuming `ZWILDCARD` has a list of entries with SQL wildcards (`%` and `_`, not `*` and `+`) on either side.  If not, you'd need to add the necessary formatting at the beginning of the loop.

Also, if you only cared about `t_wildcard` and not `t_text`, the database access could be a `select single`, further reducing the load.

Comment: Yes, but it your case, I would have the wildcard data before the text data, which is exactly the opposite scenario we have.